# error C2228: выражение слева от ".data" должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение

Tags: c++, классы, stl, struct

**реализую шаблонный класс очередь с приоритетом**

```
template <typename T> struct Element
{
public:
    T data;
    int priority;
};
template <typename T> class PQueue
{
private:
    enum { empty = -1, full = 999 };
    Element<T>  q[full + 1];
    int first;
 ...};
```

**ошибка в этом операторе :**

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os,  PQueue <T> &q)
 {
     assert(!(q.IsEmpty()));
    for (int i = q.first; i >= 0; i--)
        os << q[i].data << ", pr: " << q[i].priority << "\t";
    os << endl;
    return os;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `q` - `PQueue <T>`, оператор `[]` в нем не определен... Что такое, по-вашему, `q[i]`?

Может, вы имели в виду `q.q[i].data`?

Comment: да, это и имелось ввиду. спасибо, помогло!

Comment: Ну, тогда закрывайте вопрос, приняв ответ...